# Sqlite insert both even and odd rows in one expression

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am using sqlite3 and I have a sqlite table which has somewhat duplicated/overlapping columns. To illustrate:

```
       No    Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4
row1   1       1     1     2     2
row2   2       1     1     3     3
row3   3       2     2     4     4
row4   4       2     2     5     5
```

Col1 and Col2 stores the same information, however, Col3 and Col4 has different information.

I want to condense the rows into one row like this:

```
        No    Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col3.2  Col4.2
row1     1     1     1     2     2     3     3
row3     3     2     2     4     4     5     5
```

I have created a new table with the columns, and was able to select the odd rows.

```
INSERT INTO [Table] ( No, Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4                            
                        )
                        SELECT No, Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4  
                          FROM [Table]
                         WHERE ([No] % 2) = 1
                         ORDER BY [No];
```

The result table would be something like:

```
      No  Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4 Col3.2 Col4.2
row1  1     1     1    2     2    null   null
row3  3     2     2    4     4    null   null
```

Now I am not sure how to insert the even values into the new table. Using similar expressions only insert more rows. Is it possible to do this `INSERT INTO` expression in one sentence? Or how do I update the new table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pivoting logic with aggregation:

```
SELECT
    MIN(No) AS No,
    MAX(CASE WHEN No % 2 = 1 THEN Col1 END) AS Col1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN No % 2 = 1 THEN Col2 END) AS Col2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN No % 2 = 1 THEN Col3 END) AS Col3,
    MAX(CASE WHEN No % 2 = 1 THEN Col4 END) AS Col4,
    MAX(CASE WHEN No % 2 = 0 THEN Col1 END) AS Col1_2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN No % 2 = 0 THEN Col2 END) AS Col2_2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN No % 2 = 0 THEN Col3 END) AS Col3_2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN No % 2 = 0 THEN Col4 END) AS Col4_2
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    (No-1) / 2;
```

[image: screen capture of demo link below]

### Demo

Comment: This seems to be a very powerful way to create table!

Answer (score 2):

Just join the table with itself based on the following condition. It'll even work if the `No` column has gaps:

```sql
SELECT o.No, o.Col1, o.Col2, o.Col3, o.Col4, e.Col3, e.Col4
FROM t AS o
INNER JOIN t AS e ON  o.Col1 = e.Col1
                  AND o.Col2 = e.Col2
                  AND o.No < e.No
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, using window functions added in sqlite 3.25:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table2(no INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, col1, col2, col3, col4, "col3.2", "col4.2");
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT no, col1, col2, col3, col4, lead(col3) OVER win, lead(col4) OVER win
      FROM table1
      WINDOW win AS (ORDER BY no))
WHERE no % 2 = 1;
```

which gives

```sql
SELECT * FROM table2;
no          col1        col2        col3        col4        col3.2      col4.2    
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
1           1           1           2           2           3           3         
3           2           2           4           4           5           5
```